# iMac creates ._filename, MacBook Pro not

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, high-sierra

I’ve been searching on the forums and Google for a while now but couldn’t find a answer to my question. It’s a `._filename` related one but one who varies from the search results.

First my Hardware setup:

- iMac Retina 5K, 27 inch Late 2015 (iMac17,1), 2 TB Fusion drive, two partitions (1: High Sierra, 2: Bootcamp with Windows 8)
- Macbook Pro, 13 inch, Mid 2012 (MacBookPro9,2), 256 SSD, one partition (High Sierra)

Both machines have been reinstalled this month, both are running the latest version of macOS High Sierra with all updates installed.

- Now when I copy files to a FAT32 USB stick on my iMac it’s creating those `._filename`.
- When I do the same thing on my MacBook Pro it’s not creating those `._filename`.

I've tested it by formatting the USB Stick on the iMac, MacBook and a Windows machine (all FAT32). All had the same result.

What’s the magic behind it and how can I get both machines to behave the same?

PS: I do know I can remove those files with the `dot_clean` command but I just don't want it to happen at all, just like my MacBook does.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the text format. English isn't my native language and the auto correction isn't always giving me the correct solution.